# What is the best why to aggregate data for last 7,30,60.. days in SQL

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

Hi I have a table with `date` and the number of `views` that we had in our channel at the same day

```
date    views
03/06/2020  5
08/06/2020  49
09/06/2020  50
10/06/2020  1
13/06/2020  1
16/06/2020  1
17/06/2020  102
23/06/2020  97
29/06/2020  98
07/07/2020  2
08/07/2020  198
12/07/2020  1
14/07/2020  168
23/07/2020  292
```

No we want to see in each calendar date the sum of the past 7 and 30 days

so the result will be

```
date    sum_of_7d   sum_of_30d
01/06/2020  0   0
02/06/2020  0   0
03/06/2020  5   5
04/06/2020  5   5
05/06/2020  5   5
06/06/2020  5   5
07/06/2020  5   5
08/06/2020  54  54
09/06/2020  104 104
10/06/2020  100 105
11/06/2020  100 105
12/06/2020  100 105
13/06/2020  101 106
14/06/2020  101 106
15/06/2020  52  106
16/06/2020  53  107
17/06/2020  105 209
18/06/2020  105 209
```

so I was wondering what is the best SQL that I can write in order to get it
I'm working on redshift and the actual table (not this example) include over 40B rows

I used to do something like this:

```
select dates_helper.date
, tbl1.cnt
, sum(tbl1.cnt) over (order by date rows between 7 preceding and current row ) as sum_7d
, sum(tbl1.cnt) over (order by date rows between 30 preceding and current row ) as sum_7d 
from bi_db.dates_helper
left join tbl1
    on tbl1.invite_date = dates_helper.date
```

Comment: Please provide the sample data & expected result data in txt format not in image format.

Comment: I replaced the images with text, is it better?

Comment: There are a lot of factors to improving performance and it looks like you have omitted information.  You are joining solely on date and say you have 40B rows - that's 100 million years - and I doubt that is the data you have.  So are you doing this per some user id? I suspect there are other steps in this data processing which will be material to any recommendation.  I suspect a UNION ALL approach will be best but not if you really have 40B unique dates in your fact table.